# How do I get the SHA of HEAD in a specific git submodule?

Tags: git, bash, git-submodules

My project has multiple git submodules.  I need the SHA commit of one submodule in particular to present in the app.

`git submodule foreach` accepts a command like `rev-parse`, but it loops over all submodules, which I don't want. `git submodule status MySubmoduleFolder` gives too much output.

Comment: `git submodule status [path]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own solution.  Unlike `cut`, `awk` will ignore the first space.

```
git submodule status MySubmoduleFolder | awk '{print $1;}'
```

Comment: There was a previous answer here that suggested `cut`.

Comment: `awk` treats runs of separators as a single separator. `cut` treats them as individual separators.